# How to remove Taxonomy term Title

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Can anyone please guide me how to remove the title of the Taxonomy terms.

I would like to give the title along with the description so i want to remove the default title.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you need the [Auto Entity Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel) module. Using this module, you can automatically generate labels by a given pattern for the taxonomy term names.